# C++ String array sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am having so much trouble trying to figure out the sort function from the C++ library and trying to sort this array of strings from a-z , help please!!

I was told to use this but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
// std::sort(stringarray.begin(), stringarray.end());
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int z = 0;
  string name[] = {"john", "bobby", "dear", 
                   "test1", "catherine", "nomi", 
                   "shinta", "martin", "abe", 
                   "may", "zeno", "zack", "angeal", "gabby"};

  sort(name[0],name[z]);

  for(int y = 0; y < z; y++)
  {
    cout << name[z] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a std::vector instead of a plain array

Comment: Can you show an example please? I am kinda new to C++

Comment: Use qsort() on a separate list of pointers to your strings.

Comment: @Mattingly: Why would anybody want to use a substantially slower and a lot harder to use approach to sorting?

Comment: I suppose the question was fairly STL specific... yet I prefer to avoid STL like the plague.

Comment: @Mattingly might as well code in C then

Comment: @Mattingly not STL specific. Just C++, which means the C++ standard library too.

Comment: @Mattingly: Avoiding the STL is extremely easy. The C++ Standard Library not so much. If that's what you actually meant, why are you avoiding it "like the plague"? That seems really strange. What is your good reason for this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, that's what I meant... thanks for the correction.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: You should probably do some profiling and get some hard results before making claims.  With a quick test, a `qsort` implementation ran 3-6x faster than the `std` version, on the provided example.  Code and results provided in an answer below.

Comment: @Mattingly: I posted a corresponding response with what I would call improved measurements, trying to be fair to both `std::sort()` and `qsort()`: Adding the memory management in the case of using `std::sort()` but not when using `qsort()` seems unreasonable. Also, I didn't claim that constructing and `std::sort()`ing is faster than just just `qsort()`ing. It came as a surprise, however, that the naive approach to sorting isn't faster using `std::sort()` on larger data sets (although it compares two different things: sorting an array of `std::string`s and sorting an array of `char const*`s).

Comment: @Mattingly: Following a comment from Mooing Duck I moved the response to my [blog](http://kuhllib.com/2013/08/21/comparing-stdsort-and-qsort/).

Comment: @Mattingly: Why are you avoiding it "like the plague"? That seems really strange. What is your good reason for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
int z = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]); //Get the array size

sort(name,name+z); //Use the start and end like this

for(int y = 0; y < z; y++){
    cout << name[y] << endl;
}
```

**Edit :**

Considering all "proper" naming conventions (as per comments) :

```
int N = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]); //Get the array size

sort(name,name+N); //Use the start and end like this

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    cout << name[i] << endl;
}
```

**Note:** Dietmar Kühl's answer is best in all respect, `std::begin()` & `std::end()` should be used for `std::sort` like functions with C++11, else they can be defined.

Comment: for the love of future programmers: at the very least, rename `z` to `N` and `y` to `i`, so that it at least resembles all other code using index manipulations...

Comment: _Please_ don't get array sizes like that.

Comment: @TemplateRex, for the love of future programmers, at the very least, do not use "N". I renamed it to sname yesterday, and also 'y' to 'i'. Did you like my reply then? :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: pardon ?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I made the comment here because this answer is the accepted one, and promotes an off-beat naming convention that -while not technically *wrong*, of course- is just making it harder to read

Comment: @TemplateRex: Sure, and I referred to my IMHO correct naming convention in the reply to you. So, people can check that out in the future for proper reading. All fine, no?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I don't like `sname`, if I would use something other than `N`, i would use the more verbose but clearer `name_size`

Comment: @TemplateRex: that is just useless typing. Not to mention, it is also a can of worms for the camelCase vs under_score flamewar. sfoo is a pretty common practice out there, really.

Comment: @LaszloPapp And `N` is even less typing! For locally defined arrays that would be as concise as it gets without risking ambiguity. If more context is required, useless typing is not a relevant criterion. I like underscores myself, but in a camelCase shop, the proper name would be `nameSize`.

Comment: @LaszloPapp agreed on 1 and 3, but 2 has IMO readability problems for names starting with an s.

Comment: @TemplateRex: What readability problem? It is pretty common out there smyarr means the "size of myarr". Here is an example: sdata -> size of data. It is quite a common pattern out there. It is a _lot_ more common if you take a look at google than say... data_size.

Answer (score 35):

The algorithms use iterator to the beginning and past the end of the sequence. That is, you want to call `std::sort()` something like this:

```
std::sort(std::begin(name), std::end(name));
```

In case you don't use C++11 and you don't have `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, they are easy to define yourself (obviously not in namespace `std`):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) {
    return array;
}
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
T* end(T (&array)[Size]) {
    return array + Size;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Example using std::vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    /// Initilaize vector using intitializer list ( requires C++11 )
    std::vector<std::string> names = {"john", "bobby", "dear", "test1", "catherine", "nomi", "shinta", "martin", "abe", "may", "zeno", "zack", "angeal", "gabby"};

    // Sort names using std::sort
    std::sort(names.begin(), names.end() );

    // Print using range-based and const auto& for ( both requires C++11 )
    for(const auto& currentName : names)
    {
        std::cout << currentName << std::endl;
    }

    //... or by using your orignal for loop ( vector support [] the same way as plain arrays )
    for(int y = 0; y < names.size(); y++)
    {
       std:: cout << names[y] << std::endl; // you were outputting name[z], but only increasing y, thereby only outputting element z ( 14 )
    }
    return 0;

}
```

http://ideone.com/Q9Ew2l

This completely avoids using plain arrays, and lets you use the std::sort function. You might need to update you compiler to use the `= {...}` You can instead add them by using `vector.push_back("name")`

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be better to use `const` references in the range based for loop instead of copying the strings.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree, I just used `auto` for simplicity. Also I wasn't entirely sure what it would evaluate to in this case.

Comment: It would evaluate to `std::string`, so you could use `for(const auto& currentName : names)` to get `const std::string&` and avoid the copies.

Comment: @juanchopanza Okay, thanks. I was thinkging it could evalutate to `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` guess I'm not that famililar with C++11 yet. Updated my answer to use `const &`

Answer (score 6):

Your loop does not do anything because your counter `z` is 0 (and 0 < 0 evaluates to `false`, so the loop never starts).

Instead, if you have access to C++11 (and you really should aim for that!) try to use iterators, e.g. by using the non-member function `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, and a range-for loop to display the result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int z = 0;
    string name[] = {"john", "bobby", "dear", "test1", "catherine", "nomi", "shinta", "martin", "abe", "may", "zeno", "zack", "angeal", "gabby"};

    sort(begin(name),end(name));

    for(auto n: name){
         cout << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=89eae42692b8b47ff1b825fee2128472-1bc3b30e7813d939a8572cf8b3e715c2).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name[] = {"john", "bobby", "dear", "test1", "catherine", "nomi", "shinta", "martin", "abe", "may", "zeno", "zack", "angeal", "gabby"};

    int sname = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);

    sort(name, name + sname);

    for(int i = 0; i < sname; ++i)
        cout << name[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As many here have stated, you could use std::sort to sort, but what is going to happen when you, for instance, want to sort from z-a? This code may be useful

```
bool cmp(string a, string b)
{
if(a.compare(b) > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int main()
{
string words[] = {"this", "a", "test", "is"};
int length = sizeof(words) / sizeof(string);
sort(words, words + length, cmp);

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    cout << words[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
    // output will be: this test is a 

}
```

If you want to reverse the order of sorting just modify the sign in the cmp function.

Hope this is helpful :)

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

The multiset container uses a red-black tree to keep elements sorted.

```
// using the multiset container to sort a list of strings.
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::vector<std::string> people = {
  "Joe",
  "Adam",
  "Mark",
  "Jesse",
  "Jess",
  "Fred",
  "Susie",
  "Jill",
  "Fred", // two freds.
  "Adam",
  "Jack",
  "Adam", // three adams.
  "Zeke",
  "Phil"};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::multiset<std::string> g(people.begin(), people.end()); // """sort"""
  std::vector<std::string> all_sorted (g.begin(), g.end());
  for (int i = 0; i < all_sorted.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << all_sorted[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Adam
Adam
Adam
Fred
Fred
Jack
Jess
Jesse
Jill
Joe
Mark
Phil
Susie
Zeke
```

Note the advantage is that the multiset stays sorted after insertions and deletions, great for displaying say active connections or what not.

Answer (score 0):

> We can sort() function to sort string array.

**Procedure :**

1. At first determine the size string array.
2. use sort function . sort(array_name, array_name+size)
3. Iterate through string array/

---

**Code Snippet**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    string name[] = {"john", "bobby", "dear", "test1", "catherine", "nomi", "shinta", "martin", "abe", "may", "zeno", "zack", "angeal", "gabby"};

    int len = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);

    sort(name, name+len);

    for(string n: name)
    {
         cout<<n<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

My solution is slightly different to any of those above and works as I just ran it.So for interest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char *name[] = {"john", "bobby", "dear", "test1", "catherine", "nomi", "shinta", "martin", "abe", "may", "zeno", "zack", "angeal", "gabby"};
  vector<string> v(name, name + 14);

  sort(v.begin(),v.end());
  for(vector<string>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) cout << *i << ' ';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't get warnings about the deprecated conversions between `char const*` and `char*`? String literals are immutable. I also wouldn't accept that magic number in a code review.

Comment: (In fact, the deprecated conversion was removed in C++11, making this program ill-formed!)