# Sorting array of strings in cpp using std:sort

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to sort arrays (yes, not vectors) of strings, following some suggestions from sites such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213100/using-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-of-c-strings) one. This is the code I wrote so far, but it always prints out [this](https://pastebin.com/pFqeXTLX) long error (which has no results on google). How can this be fixed?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
//qsort(names, n, 15, (int (*)(const void *, const void *))strcmp);



int main()
{
    std::cout << "hi";
    char arr[3][6];
    strcpy(arr[0], "hello"), strcpy(arr[1], "hillo"), strcpy(arr[2], "hallo");
    std::sort(arr, arr + 3, [](char const *lhs,
                           char const *rhs) { return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0; });
    //qsort(arr, 3, 20, (int (*)(const void *, const void *))strcmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ String array sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292619/c-string-array-sorting)

Comment: Consider the element type of the array you're sorting. Arrays are not assignable, and therefore the stock swap-mechanics for exchanging rows in your array of arrays (each element is, in fact, an array of char) isn't going to work.

Comment: @WhozCraig what you're trying to say is that I have an array of arrays (strings are arrays) and since arrays are not assignable we can't swap items which is what "sort" does? then how do people on other SO questions manage to do it?

Comment: Pretty much. Throw out your decl of arr, and the strcpy calls, and replace them with `const char *arr[] = { "hello", "hillo", "hallo" };` and try again. Then consider what changed and why it now works.

Comment: @WhozCraig will using the type "string" work here? (instead of doing a 2d array doing a 1d array with each element having string type)

Comment: Using an array of `std::string` rather than an array of arrays will definitely work. Using qsort works (when properly setup) because its basically just a memory blaster at heart, with logical callbacks to determine what to swap around.

Comment: @WhozCraig it works with your method but I don't understand why... shouldn't the array still be supporting assigning?

Comment: Which array. it's the *elements* that would change with my prior proposal. Rather than an array of arrays its an array of const char pointer. The pointers *are* swappable, so std::sort works (and requires a custom callback as you're providing to get lexicographical comparison; otherwise you're just comparing pointer values, and what fun is that).

Comment: @WhozCraig so when using `const char *arr[] = { "hello", "hillo", "hallo" };` the type of each element is no longer array but some kind of string (not just an array of chars). What makes strings swappable/assignable, while arrays aren't?

Comment: Each element in that decl is a pointer; not an array of char. Arrays are not swappable (but `std::array` is, provided the dimensions properly match). I'd explain how some of this is ill-advisedly side-steppable by burying your fixed native arrays in structures, but you have enough on your plate right now.

Comment: @WhozCraig so if instead I were to dynamically allocate a pointer for each string, and store the *pointers* in the list that would indeed work? except the fact that I would probably have to change a bit the sorting algorithm to read the string from the pointer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You wouldn't have to change the sorting algorithm if you did that. In fact, the code was broken because that was what was expected *now*, and you're weren'y providing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant part of the error message:

> error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Which is not very clear unfortunately, but ot comes from within the sorting implementation. So, let us revise the preconditions of the algorithm:

`std::sort` is implemented by swapping elements. As such, it requires that the elements are swappable. The elements of your array are arrays. Arrays are not swappable. Therefore an array of arrays is not sortable.

> will using the type "string" work here?

Using  `std::string` will work. It is swappable.  You won't even  need a custom comparison function because it is even comparable.

> what makes arrays unswappable and other types swappable

Swap is inplemented by move initialisation (and assignment). Language rules say that array is not move initialisable (nor is it assignable). Knowing this, see if the error messsge makes some sense.

Comment: Thank you. what makes arrays unswappable and other types swappable?

Comment: Very interesting, I will continue exploring the subject for a deeper understanding. thank you. I will mark your answer as correct and will metion that the comments of @WhozCraig are very explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort array of arrays using sort inbuilt function.
You can traverse through the array of strings and sort each string(str) using `sort(str.begin(), str.end())`.